# Get dictionary keys and values from txt file

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

sum_buys = {}

it contains sub-dictionaries:

```
for filter in range (1, 5):
    sum_buys[filter] = {}
```

I want to fill keys and values using txt file. It stores data organized like this:

```
sum_buys[1][20200318]=2875939363.1499553
sum_buys[2][20200318]=6875492293.750077
sum_buys[3][20200318]=11475715852.6502
sum_buys[4][20200318]=15450024141.350155
```

If it is important I can change txt file:

```
'sum_buys[1][20200318]=2875939363.1499553'
'sum_buys[2][20200318]=6875492293.750077'
'sum_buys[3][20200318]=11475715852.6502'
'sum_buys[4][20200318]=15450024141.350155'
```

How to read txt file and put keys and values from lines to dictionary?
May be eval function? But it doesn't work for me:

```
with open('file.txt', "r") as file:
    lines_list = file.readlines()
    for line in lines_list:
        line = line.replace ('\n', '')
        eval (line)
```

I can use split function, but it seems to be very ugly way.

Comment: Why don't you store it in a recognised format, like JSON.

Comment: You may like the use of a `csv.DictReader` if you opt for a CSV  file. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)